# Pug template not loading CSS on Mac in safari

Tags: css, express, safari, pug

### Safari on Mac (Ventura 13.2.1) neither loads CSS nor favicon in combination with Pug.

Please help find a solution.

##### Error:

```js
Unsafe attempt to load URL https://localhost:3000/img/icons.svg from origin http://localhost:3000. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

```js
Failed to load resource: An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.
```

##### Network tab in developers mode:

```js
Summary
URL: https://localhost:3000/css/style.css
Status: —
Source: —
Initiator: 
localhost:1
```

##### Impression:

Seems that the problem is related to SSL.

##### File Location

```
root>public>css>style.css
```

##### Example of code

```js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

```js
doctype html 
html(lang='en')
    head
      link(rel='stylesheet' href='/css/style.css' type='text/css')
      link(rel='shortcut icon' type='image/png' href='/img/favicon.png')
```

##### What has been done so far:

I googled the issue and it looks like developers experience a similar issue. I tried proposed solutions and it has not fixed the issue. 
 I switched to chrome and everything works as it should.

Some examples of what has been tried:

```js
  res.set(
  'Content-Security-Policy',
  "default-src 'self';font-src fonts.gstatic.com;style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' fonts.googleapis.com"
  );
```

```html
style
  include css/style.css
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that [HSTS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/HSTS) for localhost is cached by Safari.

Or it is predefined by your server/express/helmet.

Disable it through helmet. For example like this:

```
app.use(
    helmet({
        hsts: false,
    })
);
```

And clear Safari's cache in the Settings: Privacy -> Manage Website Data

Comment: You saved the day. Greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: When app is ready for production should I enable it?

Comment: It makes sense to turn it on. Just keep in mind that the browser will not let you access the page if the SSL certificate is expired or invalid.

Comment: You could set this option like this `hsts: isProd ? true : false`